# Movement along circle around a given point 2D

Tags: android, math, opengl-es, rotation

I want to move an object on a circle around a given point. I am using OpenGL on Android and my  viewport is the screen resolution in landscape mode (1280 * 800). The point I want to rotate an object around is e.g (500, 300) and this is where the user pressed. I also have the radius of the desired circle r. 
To sum it up, I've  the center of the circle, the radius, and the angle (amount I want to move the object with each iteration of the game loop)

So far I tried this:

```
this.setPosX(((float)Math.cos(angle)*radius + center.x) * width);
this.setPosY(((float)Math.sin(angle)*radius + center.y) * height);
```

This will create a movement along an ellipsis, not a circle...

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Circles don't have widths and heights. Probably why you end up with a ellipse

Comment: How did you even come up with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It produces an ellipse cause circles DON'T have heights. Try this instead

```
this.setPosX(((float)Math.cos(angle)*radius ) + center.x);
this.setPosY(((float)Math.sin(angle)*radius ) +center.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the width and height factors at the end. If you want a circle you cannot multiply the coordinates with different factors.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is not correct because you are multiplying the correct value for a point around a circle by other different values which are not meaningful.

Think about the fact that you have `c(x,y)` which is the center and you need to move around by a value which is given by `r(cos(angle)*radius, sin(angle)*radius)`.

What you obtain is `p(x + cos(angle)*radius, y + sin(angle)*radius)`.

If you multiply these two coordinates by two other values (`width` and `height` in your formula) you are changing the factor either for the circle either for the center so you end up with not only an ellipse but an ellipse which changes its center.

So:

- circle: `p(c.x + cos(angle)*r, y + sin(angle)*r)`
- ellipse: `p(c.x + cos(angle)*w, y + sin(angle)*h)`
- your formula: `p((c.x + cos(angle)*r)*w, (c.y + sin(angle)*r)*h)` (which makes no sense)